# Using ImageView to hide/reveal another ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display an image (image1 of 629x470 pixels) in a relative layout and use another complete white image (image2 of 1896x470 pixels) to scroll over image1 to hide/reveal image1.

My image1 is visible correctly. But image2 is automatically resized to a smaller version and positioned vertically centered to image1 due to which I am not able to completely coverup image1. How do I display image2 as is so that it completely covers image1? 
*adjustViewBounds* and *scaleType* did not help.

My Layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/image2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: It'd certainly help you get better answers if you took a screenshot of what you get and a mock-up of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put some gravity for both images, e.g the below code will center them in center

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

or you can use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

you can use other gravity options too, for more about gravity, refer to this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Comment: This did not helped. Since my `Image2` is large in width, it is getting resized (rather shrinked) to smaller view.

Comment: hımm try this, on both imageviews android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Using _scaleType="centerCrop"_ covers `Image1` correctly both width & height wise, but since `Image2` is cropped to center, I miss the left edge which has some transparent pixels.

Comment: hımm how about trying other scale types? like xystart or matrix?

Comment: If I use other types then `Image2` is either cropped or resized.

Comment: of course it will be resized, because it is bigger than your layout view :)

Comment: yeah, but my requirement is not to resize. So that I can slide `Image2` over `Image1` :) Thanks a lot @onur-a

Comment: hımm then you should wrap your Image2 with scrollview, you can use horizontal or vertical or both, pick one which works best for you :) it's nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use `image2` to scroll over and cover up your `image1`, you may instead create custom layout(`linearlayout type`) for `image2` and then call it up when you make events(scroll down etc.)
2. You may use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for `image1` and use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for `image2` to set up their size.

The way you put `imageview` together in same `xml` will fix their position. `Image2` will always stay under `image1`.

Comment: The problem is `Image2` is getting resized automatically. If I use an image of same width as of `Image1` (which is 629 pixels) then it covers `Image1` correctly, but I will not be able to scroll since `Image2` would be smaller than screen width. So, since the width of `Image2` is larger (1896 pixels) its `ImageView` got shrinked into smaller in size.